# Borel Set with undefined density

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to find a Borel set $B$ and a point $x$ such that 
$$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{\mu(B\cap B_r(x))}{\mu(B_r(x))}$$

is undefined. $\mu$ is the Borel measure.

How do I approach this? I know when limit is undefined but can't find one way to make the limit undefined here.

Comment: Hint: think about concentric circles . . .

Comment: @NoahSchweber I was looking at concentric annuli but I think the limit exist for those.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you tried concentric annuli, but that the limit seemed to exist. This is not correct, though, as long as the radii shrink rapidly enough. Say we have a sequence of decreasing radii $r_1>r_2>r_3>r_4>...$, and our set $B$ consists of all points between the circles of radius $r_{2n-1}$ and $r_{2n}$, centered on the origin. Then I claim that if the radii shrink fast enough, the limit you are interested in does not exist. HINT: what happens if $${\pi r_n^2\over\pi r_{n+1}^2}\rightarrow \infty?$$ (Of course, the $\pi$s cancel; I'm writing them in as a hint . . .)

Comment: Say if we take $r_n = 1/2^n$ then this approaches $1/4$... is there a specific sequence I should be taking?